# How to get-aduser for a manager using a UPN

Tags: powershell

Im using

```
$Manager = Get-aduser ($User.Manager) -replace "@email.com"
```

To try and process a spreadsheets data based on a form. the manager item the end user puts into the form is managers email aka...their UPN but im trying to use the upn to pull and assign the aduser as the manager for the individuals im trying to process.

any ideas?

Comment: `UPN` and `mail` are definitely not the same thing, `UPN` aka `mail` is incorrect

Comment: not really cause its the username@domain.com im just trying to process it without the @domain.com part

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve, but does below help:
`$Manager = Get-ADUser $User.Manager -Properties DisplayName` then `$managerUPN = $Manager.UserPrincipalName
`